# Crawl tweets using python (date range)

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to crawl tweets for my thesis. I'm using Pattern (http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web) to crawl (and for sentiment analysis) which requires a Python (2.7) program to run.

So far I've been able to come up with the program which you can find below. It works but only for collecting the X amount most recent tweets.

**My question is**: Could you help with making it so, that I can crawl tweets between a certain date range (for example: Jan 1 2014 - Mar 31 2014) for a specific username?

(Or if not possible, increase the amount of tweets crawled at this moment (using the same program for different usernames (each of which have 1000s of tweets), I get results anywhere between 40 and 400)).

Thank you very much in advance!

(PS: If none of th above are possible, I'm more than happy to listen to alternatives to collect the necessary tweets.  I should add that I don't have a very strong background in programming.)

```
import os, sys; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", ".."))
import time
from pattern.web import Twitter, hashtags
from pattern.db  import Datasheet, pprint, pd
from pattern.en  import sentiment

try: 
    table = Datasheet.load(pd("test.csv"))
    index = set(table.columns[0])
except:
    table = Datasheet()
    index = set()

engine = Twitter(language="en")

prev = None
for i in range(1000):
    print i
    for tweet in engine.search("from:username", start=prev, cached=False):
            if len(table) == 0 or tweet.id not in index:
            table.append([tweet.id, tweet.date, sentiment(tweet.text.encode("iso-8859-15", "replace"))])
            index.add(tweet.id)
        prev = tweet.id
    # sleep time to avoid search limit error (180 requests per 15min window)
    time.sleep(5.1)


table.save(pd("test.csv"))

print "Total results:", len(table)
print
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Crawling I would recommend you to use Twitter's Streaming API..in that you will get more tweets than crawling.almost all the tweets if the rate limit is not reached upto 1% of firehose.Filters are also provided which you can use.

Python's Module for twitter's streaming api's are:-

- Twython
- twitter
- tweepy

etc...

I use Twython. It is good. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Crawling tweets isn't a great approach but it would work as long as Twitter doesn't block your scraper. I'd recommend the Twitter API (both streaming and search API's).  They would let you grab Tweets and store them in a database and do any analysis that you want to do.